# ObservableCollection sorting c#

Tags: c#, sorting, observablecollection

I'm new to C#. I need to sort my `ObservableCollection` with four kinds of sorts, but I can't understand how to do that, and my Google searches didn't help.

I thought that I could create a new observable collection like this:

```cs
var orderedByNameObservableCollection = performerList.OrderBy(p =\> p.Name);
```

...but I can't understand how to easily update the table with the new `ObservableCollection`.

My code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        }

        private static string[] Load(string filename)
        {
            List<string> strings = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                strings = new List<string>();
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    strings.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }

            return strings.ToArray();
        }

        internal string[] fileRKK;
        internal string[] fileAppeals;


        private void openFileRKKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialogRKK = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialogRKK.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                TextBlockRKK.Text = "Выбранный файл: " + Path.GetFileName(openFileDialogRKK.FileName);
                fileRKK = Load(openFileDialogRKK.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void openFileAppealsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialogAppeals = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialogAppeals.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                TextBlockAppeals.Text = "Выбранный файл: " + Path.GetFileName(openFileDialogAppeals.FileName);
                fileAppeals = Load(openFileDialogAppeals.FileName);
            }
        }

        Dictionary<string, int> staffRKK = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Dictionary<string, int> staffAppeals = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        private Dictionary<string, int> staffGeneral = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        ObservableCollection<Performer> performerList = new ObservableCollection<Performer>();


        private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Header = e.Row.GetIndex() + 1;
        }

        private void WriteInTable()
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            //СЛОВАРЬ РКК
            if (fileRKK != null)
            {
                var queryOfRKK = from line in fileRKK
                                 let searchingPerson = line.Split('\t', ';')
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     ResponsiblePerson = (searchingPerson[0] == "Климов Сергей Александрович"
                                         ? searchingPerson[1].Replace("(Отв.)", "").Trim()
                                         : searchingPerson[0].Trim()),
                                 };

                foreach (var item in queryOfRKK)
                {
                    var value = item.ResponsiblePerson.Trim().Split(' ');
                    string fio;
                    if (value.Length == 3)
                    {
                        fio = value[0] + " " + value[1].Substring(0, 1) + "." + value[2].Substring(0, 1) + ".".Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fio = item.ResponsiblePerson;
                    }

                    if (staffRKK.ContainsKey(fio))
                    {
                        staffRKK[fio]++;
                    }
                    else
                        staffRKK.Add(fio, 1);
                }
            }

            //СЛОВАРЬ ОБРАЩЕНИЙ
            if (fileAppeals != null)
            {
                var queryOfAppeals = from line in fileAppeals
                                     let searchingPerson = line.Split('\t', ';')

                                     select new
                                     {
                                         ResponsiblePerson = (searchingPerson[0] == "Климов Сергей Александрович"
                                             ? searchingPerson[1].Replace("(Отв.)", "").Trim()
                                             : searchingPerson[0]),
                                     };
                foreach (var item in queryOfAppeals)
                {
                    var value = item.ResponsiblePerson.Trim().Split(' ');
                    string fio;
                    if (value.Length == 3)
                    {
                        fio = value[0] + " " + value[1].Substring(0, 1) + "." + value[2].Substring(0, 1) + ".";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fio = item.ResponsiblePerson;
                    }

                    if (staffAppeals.ContainsKey(fio))
                    {
                        staffAppeals[fio]++;
                    }
                    else
                        staffAppeals.Add(fio, 1);
                }

            }

            //ОБЩИЙ СЛОВАРЬ 
            staffGeneral = (from p in staffRKK.Concat(staffAppeals)
            group p by p.Key into g
                select new { fio = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value) }).ToDictionary(item => item.fio,
                item => item.Count);
            
            foreach (var item in staffRKK)
            {
                performerList.Add(new Performer
                    {
                        Name = item.Key,
                        CountRKK = item.Value,
                        CountAppeals =
                            staffAppeals.ContainsKey(item.Key) ? staffAppeals[item.Key] : 0,
                        CountGeneral = item.Value + (staffAppeals.ContainsKey(item.Key) ? staffAppeals[item.Key] : 0)
                    }
                );
                staffAppeals.Remove(item.Key);
            }

            foreach (var item2 in staffAppeals)
            {
                performerList.Add(new Performer { Name = item2.Key, CountAppeals = item2.Value });
            }

            DataGrid.ItemsSource = performerList.Select(p => new
            {
                p.Name,
                p.CountRKK,
                p.CountAppeals,
                p.CountGeneral
            });

            DataGrid.Columns[0].Header = "Ответственный" + Environment.NewLine + "исполнитель";
            DataGrid.Columns[1].Header = "Количество" + Environment.NewLine + "неисполненных" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "входящих документов";
            DataGrid.Columns[2].Header = "Количество" + Environment.NewLine + "неисполненных" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "письменных " + Environment.NewLine + "обращений граждан";
            DataGrid.Columns[3].Header = "Общее количество " + Environment.NewLine + "документов и " +
                                         Environment.NewLine + "обращений";
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TextBlockTime.Text = $"{stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} мс"; ;

        }

        private void ButtonLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileRKK != null && fileAppeals != null)
            { 
               TextBlockTodayDate.Text = $"Дата составления справки: {DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}";
               Total.Text = $"Не исполнено в срок {performerList.Sum(p => p.CountGeneral)} документов, из них:";
               TotalRKK.Text = $"- количество неисполненных входящих документов: {performerList.Sum(p => p.CountRKK)};";
               TotalAppeals.Text = $"- количество неисполненных письменных обращений граждан: {performerList.Sum(p => p.CountAppeals)}.";
                WriteInTable();
                
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Вы выбрали не все файлы!");
        }

       /* private void ButtonNameSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO
            WriteInTable();

        }

       private void ButtonRKKSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO
            WriteInTable();
        }

        private void ButtonAppealsSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO
            WriteInTable();
        }

        private void ButtonGeneralSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO
           WriteInTable();
        }*/

        private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DataGrid == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Нечего выводить!");
                return;
            }
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName, false))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Справка о неисполненных документах и обращениях граждан\n");
                    writer.WriteLine(Total.Text);
                    writer.WriteLine(TotalRKK.Text);
                    writer.WriteLine(TotalAppeals.Text);
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    writer.WriteLine("{0,4} |{1,20} |{2,11} |{3,16}|{4,13} ",
                        "№", "Исполнитель", "Кол-во ркк", "Кол-во обращений", "Общее кол-во");
                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (var item in performerList)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        writer.WriteLine("{0,4} |{1,20} |{2,11} |{3,15} |{4,13} ",
                            i++, item.Name, item.CountRKK, item.CountAppeals, item.CountGeneral);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class Performer
    {
        public string Name;
        public int CountRKK;
        public int CountAppeals;
        public int CountGeneral;
        
    }
```

Maybe you can help me? Maybe you'll tell me the correct ordering or how to  write in datagrid the new observable collection?

Comment: It sounds like you may have gotten a good response, but in the future I'd recommend posting code that demonstrates the problem with the minimum amount of code possible. As is, there's a lot of other implementation details that aren't necessary for understanding the problem, and thus make this question a bit intimidating to parse.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the OrderBy() function from LINQ, the output is an IEnumerable, which is not an observable collection. So, you need to create an observable collection from the OrderBy() result

```
var orderedByName = performerList.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
DataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Performer>(orderedByName);
```

Comment: VS says: "Incorrect number of type parameters in reference to class 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` "

Comment: `new ObservableCollection<Performer>(orderedByName);`

Comment: ? Isn't this the same you write before?

Comment: I do sorting like that and with other variant: (DataGrid.ItemSource = performersList.Select().OrderBy),but txt file shows unsorted list